# Error 404 on using servlets with struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, http-status-code-404

I have all the Struts `jar` included in `WEB-INF/lib` and imported to project. I am trying to migrate from simple servlets based project to Struts2. I added filter tag in `web.xml` and constant tag in `struts.xml` as per the tutorial , yet I get 404 on servlet invocation.

**`web.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Solution</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tcs.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml` :**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/LoginController"></constant>
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">    
    </package>
</struts>
```

**error on JSP page :**

```
HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name LoginController.
The requested resource (There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name LoginController.) is not available.
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a pattern

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/LoginController/?.*"/>
```

and servlet mapping should be

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.tcs.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginController/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: under devmode= true , the error reads ,Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages: 
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name LoginController.
Stacktraces

There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name LoginController. - [unknown location]

Comment: Make sure `struts.xml` is on classpath.

Comment: I have put it under Proj src directly Solution/src/struts.xml , and also tried to put it under web-Inf Solution/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts.xml . The same error "There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name LoginController. - [unknown location]"

Comment: Try to put it into web-inf/classes, also it only make sense if the project is deployed. See updated.